# Spring MVC project upload on tomcat server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat7, tomcat8.5

I uploaded spring mvc project in two different tomcat folder for like tomcat 7.0 & tomcat 8.5, how can i access common Resource folder from two diffrent tomcat folder?

Comment: Common resource folder contains static files such as images, documents etc ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/suSy4.png     see this link images folder like this

Comment: If your copying same webapp to 2 different tomcat folders, then embedded  resources  gets duped. Are you wanting to externalize the images from web apps, so that multiple web apps can access same set of images?